# Калькулятор в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как убрать `None` при выводе факториала 4?

```
def factorial():
    t = 1
    if(x==0):
        print(t)
    else:
        for i in range(1, x+1):
            t*=i
        print(t)
s1=[]  
while True:
    x=int(input())
    op=input()
    if op=='+':
        y=int(input())
        print(x+y)
        s1.append(x+y)
    elif op=='-':
        y=int(input())
        print(x-y)
        s1.append(x-y)
    elif op=='*':
        y=int(input())
        print(x*y)
        s1.append(x*y)
    elif op=='/':
        y=int(input())
        print(x//y)
        s1.append(x//y)
    elif op=='%':
        y=int(input())
        print(x%y)
        s1.append(x%y)
    elif op=='!':
        print(factorial())
    elif op=='x':
        s1.append(x)
        print(s1[0])
```

Ввод:

```
4
!
```

Вывод:

```
24
None
```

Буду благодарен любой помощи!

Comment: может сделать чтобы функция `factorial` возвращала результат, а не печатала его

Comment: А какая разница?

Comment: Заменить `print(t)` на `return t`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы при вызове факториала пишете `print(factorial())` по этому при вызове у вас выводится  получившиеся число и `None` сам код программы:

```
def factorial():
    t = 1
    if x == 0:
        print(t)
    else:
        for i in range(1, x + 1):
            t *= i
        print(t)


s1 = []
while True:
    x = int(input())
    op = input()
    if op == '+':
        y = int(input())
        print(x+y)
        s1.append(x+y)
    elif op == '-':
        y = int(input())
        print(x-y)
        s1.append(x-y)
    elif op == '*':
        y = int(input())
        print(x*y)
        s1.append(x*y)
    elif op == '/':
        y = int(input())
        print(x//y)
        s1.append(x//y)
    elif op == '%':
        y = int(input())
        print(x%y)
        s1.append(x%y)
    elif op == '!':
        factorial()
    elif op == 'x':
        s1.append(x)
        print(s1[0])
```

---

Или так  без вызова функции

```
s1 = []
while True:
    x = int(input())
    op = input()
    if op == '+':
        y = int(input())
        print(x+y)
        s1.append(x+y)
    elif op == '-':
        y = int(input())
        print(x-y)
        s1.append(x-y)
    elif op == '*':
        y = int(input())
        print(x*y)
        s1.append(x*y)
    elif op == '/':
        y = int(input())
        print(x//y)
        s1.append(x//y)
    elif op == '%':
        y = int(input())
        print(x%y)
        s1.append(x%y)
    elif op == '!':
        t = 1
        if x == 0:
            print(t)
        else:
            for i in range(1, x + 1):
                t *= i
            print(t)
    elif op == 'x':
        s1.append(x)
        print(s1[0])
```

---

Или используя `return`

```
def factorial():
    t = 1
    if x == 0:
        print(t)
    else:
        for i in range(1, x + 1):
            t *= i
        return t


s1 = []
while True:
    x = int(input())
    op = input()
    if op == '+':
        y = int(input())
        print(x+y)
        s1.append(x+y)
    elif op == '-':
        y = int(input())
        print(x-y)
        s1.append(x-y)
    elif op == '*':
        y = int(input())
        print(x*y)
        s1.append(x*y)
    elif op == '/':
        y = int(input())
        print(x//y)
        s1.append(x//y)
    elif op == '%':
        y = int(input())
        print(x%y)
        s1.append(x%y)
    elif op == '!':
        print(factorial())
    elif op == 'x':
        s1.append(x)
        print(s1[0])
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!